# IPhone 3GS with iOS 4.2.1 does not sync with Exchange 2003 SP2 since update

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2003, synchronization, iphone

lately my boss updated his iphone 3GS to iOS 4.2.1 which is causing the email sync to fail. the problem is kinda weird because, calender and contacts do sync and sending new email from the iphone is possible too, but new incoming emails wont show up.

other mobile devices work just fine (iphone 4 & some droids)

did anybody else experienced the same problem?

i already tried the following:

- installed the profile from apple which changes the default timeout (http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/TS3398/DefaultEASTaskTimeout.mobileconfig)
- removed the self-signed ssl cert and readded it
- reentered all exchange related settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem vanished today for no apparent reason ...